# What is the piece played when Luffy uses Gear Third in Episode 288?

Tags: one-piece, music

In Episode 288 ("Fukuro's Miscalculation - My Cola is the Water of Life!"), Luffy's Gear Third is introduced when he uses it to break down a closed steel door, and proceeds to pursue Robin. What is the background piece playing at the time?

[image: Luffy getting ready to use Gear Third]

Comment: I love that scene when Luffy uses Gear Third for the first time. The background music made it more epic!

Answer (score 3):

The piece is *Luffy vs Ratchet Round 1*, composed by [Kohei Tanaka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kohei_Tanaka_%28composer%29).

It was first used in [Movie 7: Giant Mecha Soldier of Karakuri Castle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Giant_Mechanical_Soldier_of_Karakuri_Castle#ep7), which was released on March 4, 2006.

[Youtube Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GrtipI7dP2Y)